# Counting the set with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This is an interesting problem from a high school programming contest in China.

> Define a set $S=\{1,2,\ldots , n\}$ with $n$ elements. We need to choose some subset $A_{i,j}(A_{i,j}\subseteq S,1\leq j\leq i\leq k)$ which has the restriction that $\forall 1<j\leq i\leq k, A_{i,j}\subseteq A_{i,j-1},\forall i>1,1\leq j\leq i\leq k, A_{i,j}\subseteq A_{i-1,j}$. 
>   $$ \begin{array}{ccccc}A_{1,1}& & & & \\ A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} & & & \\ A_{3,1} & A_{3,2} & A_{3,3} & & \\ \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \\ A_{k,1} & A_{k,2} & A_{k,3} &\cdots & A_{k,k}\end{array}$$
>   Given $n,k$, count the number of the ways to choose $A_{1,1},\ldots, A_{k,k}$.

I tried a few cases and found the answer is always $2^{nk}$, but hard to prove it, even by induction.

What's the combinatorial explanation of the solution and how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of $S$ can be considered separately. If an element $a$ is in one of the sets, it must be in all sets to the left of and above that set. It follows that there is a boundary line separating sets containing $a$ from sets not containing $a$ that extends from the lower left corner (to the left and below $A_{k,1}$) to the diagonal (above the $A_{i,i}$) and consists of $k$ steps that are each either upwards or to the right. The steps are independent, so there are $2^k$ ways to take them, and these $2^k$ options exist for all $n$ elements independently, so the total number of arrangements is $(2^k)^n=2^{nk}$.

(The case $n=k=1$ with $2$ possible arrangements shows that your formula $2^{n+k}$ can't be right; perhaps it's a typo?)